# Chess engine in C++

Tags: c++, chess

I'm looking for experienced honest feedback on my chess engine. I don't know what you'd be looking for, but my goal is to become a better programmer.

board.h

```
/*
    File: board.h

    Content on and manipulation of a chess board implemented as 10x12 squares,
    with default out_of_border values.

    "magic" numbers will be used, they aren't magic if you know this structure.
    Source way too messy with a lot of variable names and variable calculations instead of plain numbers.

    Author: Ken Rouwas
    Date 2017-09-14
*/

#pragma once

#include <array>

namespace Chess{

    const size_t board_size = 10*12;

    enum class Color { white, black, none };

    enum class Piece {
        king,       // a king without castle potential
        king_castle,    // a king with castle potential
        queen,
        pawn,       // a pawn without en passant potential
        pawn_en_passant, // a pawn with en passant potential
        rook,
        rook_castle,
        knight,
        bishop,
        none,
        out_of_board    // Illegal position
    };

    struct Square {
        Color piece_color;
        Piece piece;
        Square(Piece, Color);
        Square();
    };

    class Board {
        private:
            std::array<Square, board_size> squares;
        public:
            void set(const size_t where, Square);
            Square get(const size_t where) const;
    };

    void init_classic_board(Board&);

}
```

Board.cpp

```
// File: board.cpp

#include "board.h"


namespace Chess {
    Square::Square(Piece p, Color c){
        piece = p;
        piece_color = c;
    }

    Square::Square(){
        piece = Piece::out_of_board;
        piece_color = Color::none;
    }


    void Board::set(const size_t where, Square s) {
        if (where >= board_size)
            return;
        squares[where] = s;
    }

    Square Board::get(const size_t where) const {
        if (where >= board_size)
            return Square (Piece::out_of_board, Color::none);
        return squares[where];
    }

    void init_classic_board(Board& b) {
        // Place pawns
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
            b.set(31 /*col 1, 2nd row*/ + i, Square(Piece::pawn, Color::black));
            b.set(81 /*col 1, 7th row*/ + i, Square(Piece::pawn, Color::white));
        }

        // Place the rest but with s/kings/queens
        int w = 0;
        for( auto p : {Piece::rook_castle, Piece::knight, Piece::bishop, Piece::queen} ) {
            b.set(21+w, Square(p, Color::black));
            b.set(28 /*col 8, 1st row*/ - w, Square(p, Color::black));
            b.set(91 /*col 1, 8th row*/ + w, Square(p, Color::white));
            b.set(98 /*col 8, 8th row*/ - w, Square(p, Color::white));
            ++w;
        }

        // Place kings
        b.set(25, Square(Piece::king_castle, Color::black));
        b.set(95, Square(Piece::king_castle, Color::white));

        // Empty squares inbetween the pieces
        for(int x=0; x < 8; ++x)
            for(int y=0; y < 4; ++y)
                b.set(41+x+y*10,Square(Piece::none, Color::none));
    }

}
```

move.h

```
/*
    File: move.h

    Move utils and move history utils.
    Assumes that a history list and the board it's used with are consistent.

    Boardhistory:
    A move event consists of a series of board changes and a "move done",
    namely BoardChange.where == (boardsize = move_done), which is pushed last for each move event.

    Author: Ken Rouwas
    Date 2017-09-14
*/

#pragma once

#include <list>
#include <vector>

#include "board.h"

namespace Chess {

    const size_t move_done = board_size;

    struct Move {
        ssize_t from, to;
        Move(ssize_t, ssize_t);
        Move();
    };

    struct BoardChange {
        size_t where;
        Square old_square;
    };

    using Boardhistory = std::list<BoardChange>;
    using MoveSet = std::vector<Move>;

    void undo_move(Board&, Boardhistory&);

    /* Castling is identified by king move to its castling destination if permitted.
       Pawn promotion move deduced.
       All other moves are unconditional moves.
    */
    void do_move(Move, Board&, Boardhistory&, Piece pawn_promotion = Piece::queen);

    MoveSet valid_moves(Board&, Color turn); // This is the move generator

}
```

move.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "move.h"

// Read move.h for specifications

namespace Chess {

    Move::Move(ssize_t _from, ssize_t _to) {
        from = _from;
        to = _to;
    }

    Move::Move(){}

    void undo_move(Board& b, Boardhistory& ml){
        if(!ml.size())
            return;
        if(ml.back().where == move_done)
            ml.pop_back();

        while(ml.size() && ml.back().where != move_done){
            b.set( ml.back().where, ml.back().old_square );
            ml.pop_back();
        }
    }

    static void do_change(Board& b, Boardhistory& bh, size_t where, Square new_square) {
        BoardChange change;
        change.old_square = b.get(where);
        change.where = where;
        bh.push_back(change);
        b.set(where, new_square);
    }

    void do_move(Move m, Board& b, Boardhistory& bh, Piece pawn_promotion){
        // Pawn promotion
        if(b.get(m.from).piece == Piece::pawn && m.to/10 == 2)
                do_change(b, bh, m.from, Square(pawn_promotion, Color::white));

        if(b.get(m.from).piece == Piece::pawn && m.to/10 == 9)
                do_change(b, bh, m.from, Square(pawn_promotion, Color::black));

        // Move rook if castling
        if(b.get(m.from).piece == Piece::king_castle && (m.from-m.to == 2 || m.from-m.to == -2)){
            if(m.to == 23){
                do_change(b, bh, 21, Square(Piece::none, Color::none));
                do_change(b, bh, 24, Square(Piece::rook, Color::black));
            }

            if(m.to == 27){
                do_change(b, bh, 28, Square(Piece::none, Color::none));
                do_change(b, bh, 26, Square(Piece::rook, Color::black));
            }

            if(m.to == 93){
                do_change(b, bh, 91, Square(Piece::none, Color::none));
                do_change(b, bh, 94, Square(Piece::rook, Color::white));
            }

            if(m.to == 97){
                do_change(b, bh, 98, Square(Piece::none, Color::none));
                do_change(b, bh, 96, Square(Piece::rook, Color::white));
            }
        }


        Piece pawn_replaced = b.get(m.to).piece;
        // Regular piece move
        do_change(b, bh, m.to, b.get(m.from));
        do_change(b, bh, m.from, Square(Piece::none, Color::none));


         // Pawn replaced empty square
        if(b.get(m.to).piece == Piece::pawn && pawn_replaced == Piece::none) {
            // En passant move
            if(b.get(m.from-1).piece == Piece::pawn_en_passant && (m.from-m.to == 11 || m.from-m.to == -9))
                do_change(b, bh, m.from-1, Square(Piece::none, Color::none));
            else if (b.get(m.from+1).piece == Piece::pawn_en_passant  && (m.from-m.to == 9 || m.from-m.to == -11))
                do_change(b, bh, m.from+1, Square(Piece::none, Color::none));
        }


        // clear flag of pawns with en passant potential
        for(size_t i=1; i < 9; ++i){
            if(b.get(50+i).piece == Piece::pawn_en_passant)
                do_change(b, bh, 50+i, Square(Piece::pawn, Color::black));
            if(b.get(60+i).piece == Piece::pawn_en_passant)
                do_change(b, bh, 60+i, Square(Piece::pawn, Color::white));
        }

        // Give two-square moved pawns en passant flag
        if(b.get(m.to).piece == Piece::pawn) {
            if(m.from/10 == 3 && m.to/10 == 5)
                do_change(b, bh, m.to, Square(Piece::pawn_en_passant, Color::black));

            if(m.from/10 == 8 && m.to/10 == 6)
                do_change(b, bh, m.to, Square(Piece::pawn_en_passant, Color::white));
        }

        // Lose castling potential
        if(b.get(m.to).piece == Piece::king_castle)
            do_change(b, bh, m.to, Square(Piece::king, b.get(m.to).piece_color));
        if(b.get(m.to).piece == Piece::rook_castle)
            do_change(b, bh, m.to, Square(Piece::rook, b.get(m.to).piece_color));

        BoardChange done;
        done.where = move_done;
        bh.push_back(done);
    }

    MoveSet valid_moves(Board& b, Color turn){
        MoveSet ret;
        Color enemy_color = (turn == Color::white) ? Color::black : Color::white;
        int pawn_dir = (turn == Color::white) ? -1 : 1;


        for(size_t from = 21 /*skip padding*/; from < 99 /*padding after this*/ ; ++from){
            if(b.get(from).piece_color == turn){
                switch(b.get(from).piece){
                    case Piece::king_castle:
                        if(from == 95 && b.get(96).piece == Piece::none && b.get(97).piece == Piece::none && b.get(98).piece == Piece::rook_castle)
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, 97));
                        if(from == 25 && b.get(26).piece == Piece::none && b.get(27).piece == Piece::none && b.get(28).piece == Piece::rook_castle)
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, 27));                  
                        if(from == 95 && b.get(94).piece == Piece::none && b.get(93).piece == Piece::none && b.get(92).piece == Piece::none && b.get(91).piece == Piece::rook_castle)
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, 93));
                        if(from == 25 && b.get(24).piece == Piece::none && b.get(23).piece == Piece::none && b.get(22).piece == Piece::none && b.get(21).piece == Piece::rook_castle)
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, 23));
                    // fallthrough
                    case Piece::king:
                        for(auto to : {from-11, from-10, from-9,from-1, from+1, from+9, from+10,from+11}) {
                            if(b.get(to).piece_color == turn || b.get(to).piece == Piece::out_of_board)
                                continue;
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, to));
                        }
                        break;
                    case Piece::pawn:
                        if(b.get(from+pawn_dir*11).piece_color == enemy_color)
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, from+pawn_dir*11));
                        if(b.get(from+pawn_dir*9).piece_color == enemy_color)
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, from+pawn_dir*9));
                        if(b.get(from+pawn_dir*10).piece == Piece::none)
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, from+pawn_dir*10));
                        if(b.get(from+pawn_dir*10).piece == Piece::none && b.get(from+pawn_dir*20).piece == Piece::none){
                            size_t row = from/10;
                            if((row == 3 && pawn_dir == 1) || (row == 8 && pawn_dir == -1))
                                ret.push_back(Move(from, from+pawn_dir*20));
                        }
                        if(b.get(from-1).piece == Piece::pawn_en_passant && pawn_dir == -1)
                            ret.push_back( Move(from, from-11) );
                        if(b.get(from+1).piece == Piece::pawn_en_passant && pawn_dir == -1)
                            ret.push_back( Move(from, from-9) );
                        if(b.get(from-1).piece == Piece::pawn_en_passant && pawn_dir == 1)
                            ret.push_back( Move(from, from+9) );
                        if(b.get(from+1).piece == Piece::pawn_en_passant && pawn_dir == 1)
                            ret.push_back( Move(from, from+11) );
                        break;
                    case Piece::knight:
                        for(auto to : {from+8, from+12, from+19, from+21, from-8, from-12, from-21, from-19}) {
                            if(b.get(to).piece_color == turn || b.get(to).piece == Piece::out_of_board)
                                continue;
                            ret.push_back(Move(from, to));
                        }
                        break;
                    case Piece::queen:
                    //fallthrough
                    case Piece::rook:
                    case Piece::rook_castle:
                        for(int dd : {1,-1,10,-10})
                            for(int d=dd; b.get(from+d).piece_color != b.get(from).piece_color && b.get(from+d).piece != Piece::out_of_board ;d+=dd) {
                                ret.push_back(Move(from, from+d));
                                if(b.get(from+d).piece != Piece::none)
                                    break;
                            }
                    if(b.get(from).piece != Piece::queen)
                        break;
                    case Piece::bishop:
                        for(int dd : {9,11,-9,-11})
                            for(int d=dd; b.get(from+d).piece_color != b.get(from).piece_color && b.get(from+d).piece != Piece::out_of_board ;d+=dd) {
                                ret.push_back(Move(from, from+d));
                                if(b.get(from+d).piece != Piece::none)
                                    break;
                            }
                        break;
                    default: // warnings unwanted
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
/*
    // File: main.cpp

    TODO: don't allow moves that leaves king in check, and count check-mate as victory. Hence, perft will be off by a few.
    TODO: prompt pawn promotion, instead of the default queen.
    TODO: handle cases of no valid moves
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "board.h"
#include "move.h"
#include "gui.h"
#include "ai.h"

using namespace Chess;


unsigned long perft(Board &b, Boardhistory &h, int depth, Color turn) {
    turn = (turn == Color::white) ? Color::black : Color::white;
    if(!depth)
        return 1;
    int leafs = 0;
    for(Move m : valid_moves(b, turn)){
        if(b.get(m.to).piece == Piece::king || b.get(m.to).piece == Piece::king_castle){
            ++leafs;
            continue;
        }
        do_move(m,b,h);
        leafs += perft(b,h,depth-1,turn);
        undo_move(b,h);
    }
    return leafs;
}


int main(){
    std::cout<<"\nChesscpu 1.0\n\n";
    std::cout<<"Commands:\nyxyx: fromto move.\n0: regret move (last AI move will be reverted as well).\n1: change color (AI will make this move)\n2: exit.\n\n";
    Board b;
    Boardhistory h;
    init_classic_board(b);

    Color turn = Color::white;
    Color ai_color = Color::black;

    bool ai_has_king = true;
    bool human_has_king = true;


    if(false) {
        unsigned long t = time(0);
        std::cout<<"DEBUG: Perft(5) result (expecting 4897256): "<<perft(b,h,5,Color::black);
        t = time(0) - t;
        std::cout<<"\nTime "<<t<<"\n";
        return 0;
    }

    if(false){
        Move mv;
        unsigned long t = time(0);
        ai_move(b, h, turn, 7, mv);
        t = time(0) - t;
        std::cout<<"\nAI Time: "<<t<<"\n";
        return 0;
    }

    Move mv {0,0};
    while(ai_has_king && human_has_king){
        print_board(b, mv);
        if(turn == ai_color)
            ai_move(b, h, turn, 7, mv);
        else
            mv = read_move(valid_moves(b, turn), turn);

        if(mv.from == 0) {
            undo_move(b,h);
            undo_move(b,h);
            continue;
        } else if (mv.from == 1) {
            ai_color = ai_color == Color::white ? Color::black : Color::white;
            continue;
        } else if (mv.from == 2) {
            human_has_king = false;
            break;
        }

        do_move(mv, b, h);
        turn = turn == Color::white ? Color::black : Color::white;

        ai_has_king = human_has_king = false;
        for(size_t i = 21; i < 99; ++i) { // board.h about these magic numbers
            if(b.get(i).piece == Piece::king || b.get(i).piece == Piece::king_castle) {
                if(b.get(i).piece_color == ai_color) {
                    ai_has_king = true;
                } else {
                    human_has_king = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    print_board(b, mv);

    std::cout<<"\n\n";
    if(!human_has_king)
        std::cout<<"You lose.";
    if(!ai_has_king)
        std::cout<<"You win.";
    std::cout<<"\n\nBye!\n\n";
}
```

ai.h

```
/*
    File: ai.h

    Takes a board, returns an heuristically optimized move.

    Author: Ken Rouwas
    Date 2017-09-14
*/

#pragma once

#include "move.h"

namespace Chess {
    int ai_move(Board& b, Boardhistory& bh, Color turn, int depth, Move& _bm, int alpha = -400, int beta = 400);
}
```

ai.cpp

```
// See board.h on "magic numbers"
// File: ai.cpp

#include "ai.h"
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


namespace Chess {
    std::mt19937 mt(time(0));


    void moveorder(MoveSet& ms) {
        std::random_shuffle(ms.begin(), ms.end());
    }

    static int evaluate_leaf(const Board& b) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(size_t i = 21; i < 99; ++i) {
            if(b.get(i).piece_color == Color::none)
                continue;
            int c = b.get(i).piece_color == Color::white ? 1 : -1;
            int v = 0;
            switch(b.get(i).piece){
                case Piece::pawn:
                case Piece::pawn_en_passant:
                    v = 1;
                    break;
                case Piece::rook:
                case Piece::rook_castle:
                    v = 5;
                    break;
                case Piece::knight:
                case Piece::bishop:
                    v = 3;
                    break;
                case Piece::queen:
                    v = 9;
                    break;
                default:
                break;
            }
            sum += c*v;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    static Color flipped_turn(Color turn) {
        if(turn == Color::white)
            return Color::black;
        return Color::white;
    }

    int ai_move(Board& b, Boardhistory& bh, Color turn, int depth, Move& _bm, int alpha, int beta) {
            /*
            MoveSet valid = valid_moves(b, turn);
            _bm = valid[mt()%valid.size()];
            return 0;
            */

        Move best_move;
        int best_score = turn == Color::white ? -300 : 300;
        if(!depth)
            return evaluate_leaf(b);

        MoveSet vmoves = valid_moves(b, turn);
        moveorder(vmoves);
                //int progress = 0; // Temporary hack to show progress
        for(Move m : vmoves){
                //if(depth == 8) // Temporary hack to show progress
                //  std::cout<<"\r"<<++progress<<"/"<<vmoves.size()<<std::flush;

            if(b.get(m.to).piece == Piece::king || b.get(m.to).piece == Piece::king_castle){
                best_score = turn==Color::white ? 200+depth : -200-depth;
                best_move = m;
                break;
            }

            do_move(m, b, bh);
            int new_score = ai_move(b, bh, flipped_turn(turn), depth-1, _bm, alpha, beta);
            undo_move(b,bh);

            if((turn == Color::white && new_score > best_score) || (turn == Color::black && new_score < best_score)){
                best_move = m;
                best_score = new_score;

                if(turn == Color::black) {
                    beta = new_score;
                    if(beta <= alpha)
                        break;
                }

                if(turn == Color::white) {
                    alpha = new_score;
                    if(alpha >= beta)
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        _bm = best_move;
        return best_score;

    }
}
```

gui.h

```
/*
    File: gui.h

    Interactive graphical interface of a chess board.

    This is temporarily a quick and dirty solution.

    Author: Ken Rouwas
    Date 2017-09-15
*/

#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "board.h"
#include "move.h"

namespace Chess {

    void print_board(const Board&, Move last_move);

    /* Returns when one of the provided valid moves is read */
    Move read_move(const MoveSet& valid_moves, Color turn);

}
```

gui.cpp

```
// File: gui.cpp
// This is quick, ugly, pragmatic, temporary.

#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>
#include "gui.h"



namespace Chess {

    using namespace std;

    static const std::map<Piece, char> sprites = { 
        { Piece::pawn,      'A' },
        { Piece::pawn_en_passant,   'P' },
        { Piece::rook,      'H' },
        { Piece::rook_castle,   'H' },
        { Piece::knight,        'F' },
        { Piece::bishop,        'I' },
        { Piece::king,      'K' },
        { Piece::king_castle,   'K' },
        { Piece::none,      '+' },
        { Piece::out_of_board,      '#' },
        { Piece::queen,         'Q' }
    };

    void print_board(const Board& b, Move last_move) {
        cout<<"\n   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8";
        for(ssize_t i=20; i < (ssize_t)board_size; ++i){
            if(i%10 == 9)
                continue;
            if(i/10 == 10)
                break;
            if(i%10 == 0) {
                cout<<"\n "<<i/10<<" ";
                continue;
            }
            char s = sprites.at(b.get(i).piece);
            if(b.get(i).piece_color == Color::black)
                s = tolower(s);
            cout<<s;
            if(last_move.from == i || last_move.to == i)
                cout<<'<';
            else
                cout<<' ';          
        }
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    }

    Move read_move(const MoveSet& valid_moves, Color turn) {
        if(cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            string dummy;
            cin >> dummy;
        }

        int in;
        Move ret;
        cout<<"Your move, "<<( turn == Color::white ? "white" : "black" )<<": ";
        cin>>in;

        // Command to undo 1 or 2 moves (2 to revert AI+own)
        if(in == 0 || in == 1 || in == 2){
            ret.from = in;
            return ret;
        }

        ret.to  = in%10+in/10%10*10;
        in /= 100;
        ret.from  = in%10+in/10%10*10;

        for(const auto m : valid_moves)
            if(m.from == ret.from && m.to == ret.to)
                return ret;
        cout<<"Invalid move\n";
        return read_move(valid_moves, turn);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. I wanted to play around with a chess engine and just picked this up, because it seemed like an uncluttered starting point. Why did you use `std::list` for board history. Simply changing that to `std::vector` as a drop in replacement is an immediate 30% speedup on your `perft` for me? You only ever `push_back` and `pop_back`. `std::vector` is good at that.

Comment: Putting `board::get()` and `board::set()` in  `board.h` allows the compiler to inline them and creates a 3x (!!) speedup.

Answer (score 8):

In general this code looks nice, it's easy to read and understand, except for a few things.

### Eliminate magic numbers

The one thing that strikes me the most is that you are using magic numbers a lot. Use descriptive variable names instead as it makes your code hard to understand in some places, e.g. here:

```
if (m.to == 23) { // why 23? What is its meaning?
    do_change(b, bh, 21, Square(Piece::none, Color::none)); // why 21?
    do_change(b, bh, 24, Square(Piece::rook, Color::black)); // why 24?
}
```

I don't agree with the explanation you've provided inside the `board.h` file that naming those numbers and calculating them would be messy - it's exactly the opposite. I, for one, don't find the explanation given in this file satisfactory - it's not always clear to me what they mean and how they've been derived. You should avoid situation in which someone has to read the code and try to figure out the meaning of the values. The less time spent on understanding the code the better.

I'd say it's generally dangerous to assume that something is obvious or needs no explanation "if you know the structure" - it's always trivial to the person developing the code and not so trivial for people trying to understand your way of doing things, including you from the future.

Also the idea of giving people hints in the comments regarding where to look for the explanation is fragile. It's very likely that you restructure your code in the future and forget to change comments like this. Besides I had to read all the code to get to this comment, and how would I know looking at only part of your project that there is this one comment in this one file that explains the numbers used in several other files?

### Prefer return value over output parameter

This function:

```
void init_classic_board(Board&);
```

should return `Board` instead of taking it by parameter. That way it's more obvious what it does. It's also easier to use, since you can write a one-liner initializing it:

```
Board b = init_classic_board();
```

Modern compilers would use copy elision here, so there's no unnecessary copying.

BTW it seems to me that this function is necessary for the object to be usable. If I'm right, consider embedding it as a private method and call it from the constructor. If you plan to add some non-classic boards in the future, you can pass an enum to the constructor that would trigger the right init method. As for now, it's easy to forget to call this function after declaring an object - the object should not be in an unitialized state after its constructor is called. It's the job of the contructor to set all the variables, not some outside function's that might be called or not.

### Don't put so much code in `main.cpp`, especially game logic code

Ideally, your `main()` should contain a couple of lines - that way your code is easier to manage and understand. If you'd divided all this code into functions of meaningful names, it would be easier to figure out what the code does. Also, avoid defining functions in main.cpp. `perft()` belongs to your game logic and is necessary for the game to be run regardless of the user interface, whereas the main.cpp itself it's going to differ depending on the interface you're going to use in the future. `perft()`'s place (as well as the code from main()) is inside the `Chess` namespace. All this code is logically tied together and is required to play a game, so the natural move would be to put it in some game_logic module. What is now inside the `main()` function should be delegated to a stand alone function of the name like `playGame()` (ideally after dividing it into smaller helper functions first).

### Use more descriptive names

Function names like `perft()` don't say much about what this function is supposed to do.

It's less of an issue, but I also thinkg `Board::get()/set()` should be renamed to `Board::getSquare()/setSquare()` - that way it's clearer what they do.

### Make `Board::get()` return const reference

It seems that you are using this method only to compare its return value against something, and you never actually copy the return value or modify it, so it's reasonable to eliminate unnecessary copying by making the return value `const Square&`.

### Format your code with readability in mind

This:

```
static const std::map<Piece, char> sprites = {
    { Piece::pawn,      '        A' },
    { Piece::pawn_en_passant,   'P' },
    { Piece::rook,              'H' },
    { Piece::rook_castle,       'H' },
    { Piece::knight,            'F' },
    { Piece::bishop,            'I' },
    { Piece::king,              'K' },
    { Piece::king_castle,       'K' },
    { Piece::none,              '+' },
    { Piece::out_of_board,      '#' },
    { Piece::queen,             'Q' }
};
```

is much easier, less eye-tiring to read and find possible bugs than this:

```
static const std::map<Piece, char> sprites = {
    { Piece::pawn,      'A' },
    { Piece::pawn_en_passant,   'P' },
    { Piece::rook,      'H' },
    { Piece::rook_castle,   'H' },
    { Piece::knight,        'F' },
    { Piece::bishop,        'I' },
    { Piece::king,      'K' },
    { Piece::king_castle,   'K' },
    { Piece::none,      '+' },
    { Piece::out_of_board,      '#' },
    { Piece::queen,         'Q' }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to start by saying that you've done a really nice job of separating out the logic from the display. Also, kudos for using actual types for things like `Color` and `Piece`. It's rare to see that around here!

I agree with everything that KJMag said in their response. Here are a few other things that I noticed.

## Naming Style

For the most part your names are fairly good. However, I notice that you're switching between CamelCase for type names and using underscores for variables and constants. That's a bit irritating. Usually you stick with one. CamelCase usually uses a capital letter for the first letter of a type name and a lowercase letter for the first letter of a variable or constant. Constants and `enum`s are either all caps (not my personal preference) or start with a prefix - either `k` (e.g. kKing, kPawn, kRook, etc.) or an abbreviation of the type name (pKing, pPawn, pRook, etc.).

## Avoid Constructors That Don't Produce A Valid Object

You have a constructor for `Square` that takes no arguments and produces a square that has an invalid `piece` and `piece_color`. What is its purpose? Same with the constructor for `Move` that takes no arguments. When an object is constructed, it should be constructed completely. By making it impossible to construct an invalid object you eliminate a whole class of bugs.

## Using a 1D Array as a 2D Array

It's fine to use a 1D Array to represent a 2D object. It can be more efficient to do so. But users of a class that does that internally shouldn't have to know about it and figure out how to deal with it. For example, the `init_classic_board()` function shouldn't have to pass in `31` to represent the 1st column and 2nd row. It should be able to pass `1, 2` for that. Doing this would probably make it easier to eliminate those magic numbers, too!

## Use More Whitespace

The `valid_moves()` function is very hard to read for a variety of reasons. One of those reasons is that the code is all crammed together. I recommend using more horizontal and vertical whitespace. It would be nice to see spaces before and after every operator. So this:

```
if(b.get(from+pawn_dir*11).piece_color == enemy_color)
    ret.push_back(Move(from, from+pawn_dir*11));
```

would look like this:

```
if(b.get(from + pawn_dir * 11).piece_color == enemy_color)
    ret.push_back(Move(from, from + pawn_dir * 11));
```

I nearly missed the `+` operator between `from` and `pawn_dir`. I would also add spaces between each of the `if` statements. You may argue that this makes the function a lot longer. You're right, and that's why you should take each of those `case` statements and put them into separate functions. For example you could make a `valid_pawn_move()` function.

Building an array inside of a `for` clause is something new to me. It's very hard to read and confusing. I recommend just writing the array out before the `for`.

Comment: Good points. As for the naming style, I would argue that if you are consistent about naming functions with camel case and using underscores in variable names, it makes it much easier to distinguish them visually. It is a matter of personal taste though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is easily understandable. There are several things that I like about it:

- The use of demystified numbers to represent the board positions. I agree with you that there is nothing magical about them.
- Your choice of the obvious, most simple names for all the things you operate upon, like `king, pawn`.

Things I would do different:

- I would try to make the a1 square number 11 instead of 21, so that you can use more natural numbers (11 to 88) to refer to the squares on the board.
- The board history should not be called `ml`; I dont understand that name.

Some more remarks, from top to bottom:

```
void Board::set(const size_t where, Square s) {
    if (where >= board_size)
        return;
    squares[where] = s;
}
```

Instead of returning, you should throw an exception since trying to modify the board outside of its borders is clearly a programming mistake on a 10x12 board. Same for `Board::get`.

I would inline the two constructors for `Chess::Square`.

Having `const size_t` parameters is not useful since `size_t` variables are always passed by value. At least in the declarations the `const` should be omitted. In the implementation it's acceptable, though.

In `init_classic_board`, the code for placing the pieces is so complicated (first place a queen, then replace that with a king) that you could also just have 16 equal lines, each for one piece. Or a little helper function taking a color and a list of 8 pieces, like this

```
place_pieces(91, Color::black,
    Piece::rook, Piece::knight, Piece::bishop, Piece::queen,
    Piece::king, Piece::bishop, Piece::knight, Piece::rook);
fill_row(81, Color::black, Piece::pawn);
fill_row(71, Color::none, Piece::none);
fill_row(61, Color::none, Piece::none);
fill_row(51, Color::none, Piece::none);
fill_row(41, Color::none, Piece::none);
fill_row(31, Color::black, Piece::pawn);
place_pieces(21, Color::white,
    Piece::rook, Piece::knight, Piece::bishop, Piece::queen,
    Piece::king, Piece::bishop, Piece::knight, Piece::rook);
```

Regarding the braces: whenever an inner `for` loop needs curly braces, I also put braces around the outer `for` loop. I only omit the braces for one-liners and block statements with a one-liner body statement.

Below the `case Piece::rook_castle:`, the `if` clause has wrong indentation. You should let your IDE format the code for you. This would also make the space between `){` consistent.

Before the `case Piece::bishop:`, there is a `// fallthrough` comment missing.

After the `default:`, the `break` has wrong indentation.

In `read_move`, the `cin>>in` must be enclosed in an `if` clause.

Comment: Once you understand the numbering system it's indeed not magical, but their structure is not explained anywhere either.

Comment: It _is_ explained in the `board.h` comment that mentions the `10x12 squares`. This 10x12 implementation [is so common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_representation_(chess)#Array_based) that there is nothing magical about it to chess programmers.